# Simple Unity 2d pixel art animation - Why is my sprite distorted and moved to the right when animated?

Tags: unity, 2d, rendering

Need some help w/ weird problem during basic 2d animation. I have the following hierarchy:

[image]

Where ritual is animated to translate deerhead up and down, shift color of pentagram, and pentagram is animated to just cycle through sprites and make the candles flicker (pentagram itself does not change)
When I hit play, the pentagram distorts to the right by one pixel and the left most pixels freak
:

[image: Before]

After:

[image]

It just shifts by one pixel to the right.

- When I turn the sprite renderer off, it doesn't shift
- The x position of either transform doesn't change
- I'm using the pixel perfect camera, settings posted below
- I'm 100% certain that the sprite itself doesn't move on any frame except to flicker the candles
- Scene view does not show the problem even while it's being played, indicating to me that it's possibly the camera or something in the rendering pipeline
- Anti-Aliasing is turned off in quality settings
- Sprite asset has no compression, no filter

[image]

It's driving me mad and I've no idea how to troubleshoot further :frowning:

Any advice on how to generally troubleshoot problems like this independently appreciated, I'm just getting started :)